# Making the matplotlib Figure to occupy entire Canvas Area

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am going through the following example code of matplotlib present at "https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html". I am having a doubt/issue:- After running the code it plots/draws the figure onto the 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' pretty well. Now if I use the "pan axes" feature of 'NavigationToolbar2Tk', I am able to pan/move the axes of the plot and  correspondingly the drawn/plotted figure moves. Now I want that the axes of the figure should coincide with the canvas dimensions i.e. after plotting the figure on the canvas, the plot should fully occupy the canvas and if I use "pan axes" feature, the figure should move across the whole canvas with no white spaces in the "top"/"bottom"/"left"/"right" area if the axes is moved in that particular area of the canvas.

In the following code I tried to change the figure size/dimensions mentioned in the line "fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)" but couldn't succeed.

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate


button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if the window is
# closed with the window manager.
```

As an example of the expected result I can give an example of ARCMAP/QGIS software's console, wherein the plot fully occupies the canvas area and if we move the plot/pan the axes of the plot, the figure moves across the whole area of the canvas and not within the bounding box.

Any help will be of great use.

Edited Actual Code:

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tkinter.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas1.draw()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1,root)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.X, padx=8)

canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, padx=10, pady=5)

canvas1._tkcanvas.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, padx=10, pady=5)

def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas1, toolbar)


canvas1.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)

def _load():
    import rasterio as rio
    from rasterio.plot import show
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, right=1, top=1, left=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)

#    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

    with rio.open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\t1.tif') as src_plot:
        show(src_plot, ax=ax, cmap='gist_gray')
    plt.close()
    ax.set(title="",xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    canvas1.draw()

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Load", command=_load)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

The issue here is after the '.tif' file is plotted on the canvas and subsequently if I use the "pan axes" button the figure is moving inside the box placed inside the canvas and not across the whole canvas area as it used to happen in ArcMap/QGIS.

Comment: You can replace `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` by `ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])`

Comment: The previous comment also cuts off the axes, I'm not sure if that's what you want? If not, `fig.tight_layout(pad=0)`, possibly even combined with `ax.plot(..., clip_on=False)` might give what you want.

Comment: Thanks all of you for responding to my query. For the code provided above the solutions are working perfectly. However when I am trying to implement the same logic in my actual code (see edited post) which incorporates display of ".tif" file on tkinter canvas using rasterio library, the issue is still there. Request you all to Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

once you run the program, go to subplots settings and play with the parameters.

now you know that need to change those paramaters to a specific value.with this function:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

the default values can be shown here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html

Comment: Hi Mohammad El Assal....Your solution worked for my original post....But when I am trying to use the same in my edited post where I am trying to display ".tiff" file on the canvas, then it's not working....